# segmentation fault while trying to manipulate bits

Tags: c, pointers, bit-shift, bit

I am studying through a book called Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective to gain some insight about the inner workings of modern computers.

Tonight I was trying to look inside int's and unsigned's to see of what bits they are made. I came up with this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char * byte_pointer;
void bp2b(byte_pointer bp, bool bits[8]){
   unsigned char n;
   for (n = 0; n<8; n++){
      if (*bp & (1 << n))
         bits[7-n] = true;
      else bits[7-n] = false;
   }
}
void show_byte(byte_pointer bp){
   int ind;
   bool bits[8];
   bp2b(bp, bits);
   for (ind = 0; ind < 8; ind++){
      printf("%d",bits[ind]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
   int x;
   x = 1;
   show_byte((byte_pointer) x);
}
```

Why did I get a segfault? My knowledge of C is fairly limited, so don't hesitate to point out mistakes that seem obvious to you.

EDIT: forgot the main function.

Comment: Did you try compiling with -g and running it through aa debugger to see where the segfault occurs?

Comment: Unsigned are made of the very same bits as signed.

Comment: @Quirliom Did not, will think of it next time I come across such an error, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I hope you do know that the posted code does not cleanly compile.   Here is the error message: "25:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint0to-pointer-cast]"  pointing to this line: 'show_byte((byte_pointer) x);'

Comment: You don't need to specify array size in function declaration because it'll be decayed into pointers anyway

Comment: @LưuThanks, the intention was to document it (for myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting a non-pointer value to a pointer: `(byte_pointer) x` and then dereferencing it, this won't work. Try to take the address of `x` and cast that: `(byte_pointer) &x` instead.

Make this change and your program will run, but be aware that casting an int to an unsigned char might lead to loss of information as the unsigned char is a narrower type than the int (in most implementations).

Setting `x = 255` will yield `11111111` while setting `x = 256` will yield `00000000`.

Comment: Thanks! The call to the function was just a filler, but the error intrigued me.